# Objective C: How do I draw lines with alpha in quad curve

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm having trouble in points when i'm using a quad curve point.. I want to set the opacity to my lines but i also see points here it is.. 
here are my codes..

```
CGPoint midPoint(CGPoint p1,CGPoint p2)
{
    return CGPointMake ((p1.x + p2.x) * 0.5,(p1.y + p2.y) * 0.5);
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event//upon touches
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    previousPoint1 = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    previousPoint2 = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    currentTouch = [touch locationInView:self.view];
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event//upon moving
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    previousPoint2 = previousPoint1;
    previousPoint1 = currentTouch;
    currentTouch = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    CGPoint mid1 = midPoint(previousPoint2, previousPoint1); 
    CGPoint mid2 = midPoint(currentTouch, previousPoint1);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(1024, 768));
    [imgDraw.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineCap(context,kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, slider.value);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, blendMode);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context,red, green, blue, 0.5);
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, mid1.x, mid1.y);
    CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(context, previousPoint1.x, previousPoint1.y, mid2.x, mid2.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    imgDraw.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    endingPoint=currentTouch;
}
```

any answer will be appreciated.

Comment: I think the problem is that the end of each curve you draw overlaps with the beginning of the next one.  Unfortunately I can't immediately think of a simple solution to this problem.  What kind of background are you drawing over?

Comment: Can you give some more background on what you're trying to accomplish? At first glance, this much more complex than just using a UIGestureRecognizer to track touches and overriding drawRect for drawing.

Comment: I just want to draw a lines in an empty UIImageView that  can set the opacity of it..

Comment: Any reason why you're using UIImageView and not UIView?

Comment: The problem, in plain English, is that you're drawing a number of overlapping lines instead of a single path. user1118321's answer is a good one: he/she shows you how to collect the points and draw the entire path instead of adding individual lines, and that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is keep the list of all points the user has entered so far, and always redraw all of them as part of the same path.

You'll need an array to store the points in. Something like

```
CGPoint points[kMaxNumPoints];
```

instead of previousPoint1/2, etc. Then in `touchesMoved:`, you'll iterate over the points in a loop. Something like this:

```
CGContextBeginPath (context);
CGContextMoveToPoint (context, points [ 0 ].x, point [ 0 ].y);
for (int i = 1; i < currNumPoints; i++) 
{
    // I wasn't sure from your example if you wanted the mid point here instead of the 
    // previous point. But you get the idea.
    CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint (context, points [ i - 1 ].x, points [ i - 1 ].y, point [ i ].x, point [ i ].y);
}
CGContextStrokePath (context);
```

Comment: When I tried to implement your given code I comment out my CGContextMoveToPoint and CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint.. the problem is you remove the 2points that making a quad curve.. I'm sorry just got the logic but i don't know how to use your given code.. :(

Comment: I've updated my code above to show you my whole code.. Hopes this make easier for you this time.